# Multithreaded rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

I'm writing a rake task that would be called every minute (possibly every 30 seconds in the future) by Whenever, and it contacts a polling API endpoint (per user in our database). Obviously, this is not efficient run as a single thread, but is it possible to multithread? If not, is there a good event-based HTTP library that would be able to get the job done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I'm writing a rake task that would be called every minute (possibly every 30 seconds in the future) by Whenever

Beware of Rails startup times, it might be better to use a forking model such as Resque or Sidekiq, Rescue provides https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler which should be able to do what you need, I can't speak about Sidekiq, but I'm sure it has something similar available (Sidekiq is much newer than Resque)

> Obviously, this is not efficient run as a single thread, but is it possible to multithread? If not, is there a good event-based HTTP library that would be able to get the job done?

I'd suggest you look at [ActiveRecord's `find_each`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each) for tips on making your finder process more efficient, once you have your batches you can easily do something using threads such as:

```
#
# Find each returns 50 by default, you can pass options
# to optimize that for larger (or smaller) batch sizes
# depending on your available RAM
#
Users.find_each do |batch_of_users|
  #
  # Find each returns an Enumerable collection of users
  # in that batch, they'll be always smaller than or 
  # equal to the batch size chosen in `find_each`
  #
  #
  # We collect a bunch of new threads, one for each
  # user, eac 
  #
  batch_threads = batch_of_users.collect do |user|
    #
    # We pass the user to the thread, this is good
    # habit for shared variables, in this case
    # it doesn't make much difference
    #
    Thread.new(user) do |u|
      #
      # Do the API call here use `u` (not `user`)
      # to access the user instance
      #
      # We shouldn't need to use an evented HTTP library
      # Ruby threads will pass control when the IO happens
      # control will return to the thread sometime when
      # the scheduler decides, but 99% of the time
      # HTTP and network IO are the best thread optimized
      # thing you can do in Ruby.
      #
    end
  end
  #
  # Joining threads means waiting for them to finish
  # before moving onto the next batch.
  #
  batch_threads.map(&:join)
end
```

This will start no more than `batch_size` of threads, waiting after each `batch_size` to finish.

It would be possible to do something like this, but then you will have an uncontrollable number of threads, there's an alternative you might benefit from here, it gets a lot more complicated including a ThreadPool, and shared list of work to do, I've posted it as at Github so'as not to spam stackoverflow: https://gist.github.com/6767fbad1f0a66fa90ac

Comment: I'm pretty sure `find_each` returns the single instance (i.e. a single `user`), not the batch (i.e. a batch of `users`). `find_in_batches` is what returns the batch.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/) which is great at multithreading. You can then enqueue separate jobs per user for polling the API. [clockwork](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork) can be used to make the jobs you enqueue recurring.